# Confused by rspec feedback from assert_select test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm just getting going with rails and have a test for the index page for my `Plants` model:

**The rspec test** fails with this message:

```
$ rspec spec/views/plants/index.html.haml_spec.rb
Failures:

  1) plants/index renders a list of plants
     Failure/Error: assert_select "tr>td", :text => plant.height, :count => 2

     Minitest::Assertion:
       <48> expected but was
       <Rose Mallow>..
       Expected: 2
         Actual: 0
     # /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/minitest-5.9.1/lib/minitest/assertions.rb:139:in `assert'
     # /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/minitest-5.9.1/lib/minitest/assertions.rb:174:in `assert_equal'
     # /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/rails-dom-testing-1.0.7/lib/rails/dom/testing/assertions/selector_assertions.rb:278:in `assert_size_match!'
     # /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/rails-dom-testing-1.0.7/lib/rails/dom/testing/assertions/selector_assertions.rb:175:in `block in assert_select'
     # /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/rails-dom-testing-1.0.7/lib/rails/dom/testing/assertions/selector_assertions.rb:174:in `tap'
     # /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/rails-dom-testing-1.0.7/lib/rails/dom/testing/assertions/selector_assertions.rb:174:in `assert_select'
     # ./spec/views/plants/index.html.haml_spec.rb:15:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.19797 seconds (files took 3.07 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/views/plants/index.html.haml_spec.rb:9 # plants/index renders a list of plants
```

I guess I have two questions:

1. Why is it looking for `<48>`?  Are the lt/gt symbols just wrapping the string it is looking for (which seems a poor delimiter choice), or is it really expecting an html element named "48"?
2. And more importantly, why can't it find the two instances of the height? When I do `put render` in the test I see exactly two instances rendered:

**rendered test markup:**

```
<h1>Listing plants</h1>
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Scientific name</th>
<th>Height</th>
<th>Width</th>
<th>Spacing</th>
<th>Life cycle</th>
<th>Sun</th>
<th>Sow method</th>
<th>Direct seed start</th>
<th>Direct seed stop</th>
<th>Indoor seed start</th>
<th>Indoor seed stop</th>
<th>Transplant start</th>
<th>Transplant stop</th>
<th>Garden</th>
<th></th>
<th></th>
<th></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Rose Mallow</td>
<td>Lavatera trimestris</td>
<td>48</td>
<td>18</td>
<td></td>
<td>annual</td>
<td>full_sun</td>
<td>direct</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td>Default Test Garden</td>
<td><a href="/plants/1">Show</a></td>
<td><a href="/plants/1/edit">Edit</a></td>
<td><a data-confirm="Are you sure?" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/plants/1">Destroy</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Rose Mallow</td>
<td>Lavatera trimestris</td>
<td>48</td>
<td>18</td>
<td></td>
<td>annual</td>
<td>full_sun</td>
<td>direct</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td>Default Test Garden</td>
<td><a href="/plants/1">Show</a></td>
<td><a href="/plants/1/edit">Edit</a></td>
<td><a data-confirm="Are you sure?" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/plants/1">Destroy</a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<br>
<a href="/plants/new">New Plant</a>
```

Here's the test: **spec/views/plants/index.html.haml_spec.rb**

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe "plants/index", type: :view do
  before(:each) do
    plant = FactoryGirl.create(:plant_rose_mallow)
    assign(:plants, [ plant, plant ])
  end

  it "renders a list of plants" do
    render
    plant = FactoryGirl.create(:plant_rose_mallow)
    puts plant.inspect
    assert_select "tr>td", :text => plant.name, :count => 2
    assert_select "tr>td", :text => plant.scientific_name, :count => 2
    assert_select "tr>td", :text => plant.height, :count => 2
    assert_select "tr>td", :text => plant.life_cycle, :count => 2
    assert_select "tr>td", :text => plant.sun, :count => 2
    assert_select "tr>td", :text => plant.sow_method, :count => 2
  end
end
```

Here's my factory: **spec/factories/plants.rb**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :plant do
    association :garden, :factory => :garden

    factory :plant_rose_mallow do
      name "Rose Mallow" 
      scientific_name "Lavatera trimestris"
      height 48
      width 18
      life_cycle :annual
      sun :full_sun
      sow_method :direct
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your assert_select to use a string instead of an integer:

```
assert_select "tr>td", :text => plant.height.to_s, :count => 2
```

Your errors are a result of it searching for an integer and this will resolve them.

Comment: Hmm interesting. My whole point for using `text:` (it's the only value in my hash arg) was to force string matching instead of counting. Seems like `text:` should implicitly convert the arg to string. What other use case could there be?